# Conflito entre botões ao enviar formulário com jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Estou com um problema ao enviar um formulário jQuery, o submit era para ser feito apenas por um botão mas eu tenho dois no formulário, e o submit é feito pelos dois. como resolver esse problema??

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#resultados').hide(); 

$("#formulario").submit(function() { 

$('#resultados').show(); 
$('#resultados').html("resultados");
return false;
});
});

</script>


<div id="resultados"></div>

  <form  method="POST" id="formulario"  action="">

   <input type="submit"  value="enviar" id="botao_enviar" name="enviar">
   <button>outro botão</button>       
    </form>
```

Comment: Primeiro coloque todo o `js` antes do fechamento da `body`

Comment: Coloque o outro botão desta forma `<button type="button">outro botão</button>`, veja se funcione.

Comment: depois é só definir o `button` assim `<button type="button">Outro botão</button>`

Comment: obrigado pessoal, funcionou aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve definir o `type` do `<button>` pois o valor **padrão** para a maroria dos navegadores é **submit**, tendo como exceção somente o IE7 e suas versões anteriores onde o `type` padrão é **button**.

> **type**  define o tipo de botão, seus possíveis valores são:
>
> - **submit**: O botão envia os dados do formulário para o servidor. Esse é o padrão se o atributo não for especifidado, ou se o atributo
>     é dinamicamente mudado para um valor vazio ou inválido.
> - **reset**: O botão restaura todos os controles para seus valores iniciais.
> - **button**: O botão não possui comportamento padrão. Ele pode ter scripts do lado do cliente associado com os eventos do elemento, no
>     qual são acionados quando o evento ocorrer.

[Referência button MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

[Refência button W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5)

Segue exemplo funcionando com seu código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#resultados').hide(); 

  $("#formulario").submit(function() { 

  $('#resultados').show(); 
  
  $('#resultados').html("resultados");
    return false;
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="resultados"></div>
<form  method="POST" id="formulario"  action="">

  <input type="submit"  value="enviar" id="botao_enviar"    name="enviar" />
  
  <button type="button">Outro botão</button>       
  
</form>
```

Answer (score 6):

Tens de usar `type="button"` se não o browser pensa que é um botão de submeter.

Muda

```
<button>outro botão</button>
```

para

```
<button type="button>outro botão</button>
```

[Na MDN pode ler-se sobre o `type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type):

O possíveis valores são:

- `submit`: O botão envia os dados do formulário para o servidor. **Esse é o padrão se o atributo não for especifidado**, ou se o atributo é dinamicamente mudado para um valor vazio ou inválido.
- `reset`: O botão restaura todos os controles para seus valores iniciais.
- `button`: O botão não possui comportamento padrão. Ele pode ter scripts do lado do cliente associado com os eventos do elemento, no qual são acionados quando o evento ocorrer.